Jquery UI draggable and contenteditable conflict
I found that jquery ui draggable event and contenteditable="true" is in conflict. I mean its always draggable and you cant select text to edit.
Becuse of that I write a code:
  $('.custom_element').draggable(
  { 
    
    drag: function(event, ui) {
            
          },
          beforeStart: function () {
            
            if ($('.controls-handle').css('display') === 'none') {
                        // Allow dragging from any part of the element
                        $(this).draggable("option", "cancel", false);
                    } else {
                        // Use cancel option to prevent dragging when interacting with contenteditable elements
                        $(this).draggable("option", "cancel", "h1, h1 *");
                    }
          },

but it doesn't works properly... I mean it work first time but after that it doesn't take beforeSTart event ... it not draggable , and control-handle display doesn't make any change...
What I want to do if user click on div .custom_element then to use option cancel but after div lose focus again to be draggable (to do not use option cancel )

Please provide a [mcve]. I would suggest you define a Handle which can help avoid click ambiguity.
